# C++ or C# module documentation tool for both API reference and online book

Tags: c++, c#, documentation-generator

There are some documentation tools for C++ or C# module developers.

Doxygen: Best for generating cross-reference API reference documentation, but it is hard to author an online book (overview, tutorial, etc.)

Wiki: Best for writing online book (overview, tutorial, etc.) but it is hard to add links to every API functions.

Is there any combination of Docygen and Wiki thing?

Comment: doxygen can generate a online book, see e.g. the doxygen documentation which is written in doxygen. This might look a bit harder but when a user / developer uses it already for the code the step is not that large and doxygen also supports, a part of, markdown.

Answer (score 1):

[Sphinx-Doc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) is a python tool for generating documentation from ReStructuredText files & python source but can be used with [Breathe](http://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to interact with DoxyGen for processing C/C++ files.

The output from Sphinx can be any/all of HTML, LaTeX, PDF, etc.